# using "in" with a case statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to write something like

Case when a in (value1,value2) then b else a end

Answer (score 9):

YES.

try it out with a simple query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 2 in (1,2) then 'B' ELSE 'A' END
```

OUTPUT:

```
----
B

(1 row(s) affected)
```

then:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 3 in (1,2) then 'B' ELSE 'A' END
```

OUTPUT:

```
----
A

(1 row(s) affected)
```